# Gettting the training data in ecery batch keras

Tags: keras, deep-learning, loss-function

I would like to know if it is possible to get the set of training data used in every batch keras.

It's easy to get y_true and y_pred, but I want to know the set of trainig data used to predict in that batch.

```
def my_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    loss=K.mean(K.abs(y_true-y_pred))
    return loss

model.compile(loss=my_loss, optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['mae'])
```

This is **OK**

but I want something like this:

```
def my_loss(y_true, y_pred, x_train):

my_loss() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x_train'
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass parameters other then `y_true` and `y_pred`, You can define your custom loss like this:

```
def custom_loss(x_train):

    def my_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        loss=K.mean(K.abs(y_true-y_pred))
        # do something with x_train
        return loss

    return my_loss
```

While compiling you can pass tensor of shape same as your `x_train`.

```
input_tensor = Input(shape=input_shape) #specify your input shape, same as x_train.
model.compile(loss=custom_loss(input_tensor), optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['mae'])
```

This is how you can define your custom loss. Further you want get current batch of `x_train`, Now batching is something that you'll have to handle yourself.

Finally while training you can use [model.train_on_batch](https://keras.io/models/model/#train_on_batch).

Comment: Thanks, now I have some new information to contiinue